# Stuck on how to display an error message if no emp id is found

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Question is I have a query that looks at my emp_id text box once something is typed in it searches for the information tied to that emp_id which in my other table that it searches for its called ID.. If the emp_id matches the id in my visual model it will populate their first name and last name for them. I would like to know how I can get it to display an error if no emp_id matches an id in my visual model....  With what I have so far I get a nomethod error for first name for nil class in app/controller/populate_form which I im not sure why my guess is when it finds no match it thinks that its a nil and returns nothing..Im at a bit of a lose any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!!

This is my visual model

```
 class Visual < ActiveRecord::Base

 establish_connection :vtest

 self.table_name = 'employee'


 Visual.inheritance_column = 'inheritance_type'

 belongs_to :user

 def emp_matches(x)
   (x.id.to_i == self.id.to_i ? true : false)
 end
end
```

This is my user controller that has the my populate form method

```
 class UserController < ApplicationController


   def populate_form

     @visual = Visual.find_by_id(params[:emp_id])

     if @emp_matches == 'False'

       respond_to do |format|

         format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity, flash[:error] => "Error No ID found." }
     end

   else

     @visual = Visual.find_by_id(params[:emp_id])

     @emp_first_name = @visual.first_name

     @emp_last_name = @visual.last_name


      render :json => {

         :emp_first_name => @emp_first_name,
         :emp_last_name => @emp_last_name
      }
  end
end
```

And this is my view..

```
<div class='row form-group'>
   <div class='col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5 text-right'>
    <%= f.text_field :emp_id, tabindex: 1, id: 'emp_id', autofocus: true, placeholder: t( 'login_label' ), class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
</div>

 <div class='row form-group'>
  <div class='col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5 text-right'>
    <%= f.text_field :emp_first_name, tabindex: 1, id: 'emp_first_name', autofocus: true, placeholder: t( 'login_label' ), class: 'form-control' %>
   </div>
 </div>
```

And here is my App.js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   $('#emp_id').change(function() {
         var url = "/user/populate_form?emp_id="+$(this).val();
         $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
           if(!(data.emp_first_name === undefined))
           $('#emp_first_name').val(data.emp_first_name);
           if(!(data.last_name === undefined))
           $('#emp_last_name').val(data.emp_last_name);
         });
       }
     );
   });
```

My tables

Visual model

```
      Table is called Employee 
        ID
        emp_first_name
```

User model

```
      Table is called User 


        emp_id
```

So it would look like this???

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#emp_id').change(function() {
      var url = "/user/populate_form?emp_id="+$(this).val();
      $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        if(!(data.emp_first_name === undefined))
        $('#emp_first_name').val(data.emp_first_name);
        if(!(data.last_name === undefined))
        $('#emp_last_name').val(data.emp_last_name);
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:  "/user/populate_form?emp_id="+$(this).val();

     })
      .done(function (response) {
          if (response.success == 'success') {
              //alert('success');

          } else {
              //alert('fail');
          }
      }).error(function(data) {
        //show json error response from the server
        $("#show_error").html("<span class='text-danger' ><b>" + data.responseText + "</b></span>");
      });
    });
  }
);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

use this form of ajax request with .[error](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method

```
     .ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  "/user/populate_form?emp_id="+$(this).val();

         })
          .done(function (response) {
              if (response.success == 'success') {               
                  //alert('success');    

              } else {
                  //alert('fail');
              }
          }).error(function(data) {
            //show json error response from the server
            $("#show_error").html("<span class='text-danger' ><b>" + data.responseText + "</b></span>");
          });
```

**in the controller**

```
   format.js { render :json => @user.errors.full_messages.join(' '), :status => 400 }
```

Comment: I updated my question with your answer not sure if the syntax is is correct but, is that how it should look... Ive never really used ajax request so this is new territory for me.

Comment: @user3910236...yes ..you should get the alert ..use console.log to see where the code executes when the error comes... it should come in the .error loop...try it

Comment: I tried this but im still getting a  noMethodError (undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/user_controller.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in populate_form'
  app/controllers/user_controller.rb:24:in `populate_form'

Comment: I checked my web console as well and its saying this TypeError: elem.nodeName is undefined @Milind